# What are different between Code A and Code B in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm a beginner of Kotlin, could you tell me what are different between Code A and Code B in Kotlin? Thanks!

**Code A**

```
class Person(val firstName: String, val lastName: String, var age: Int){
}
```

**Code B**

```
class Person(firstName: String, lastName: String, age: Int){
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html for further details, but in short:

- **Code B** declares parameters for the default constructor, but doesn't do anything with them.
- **Code A** also declares parameters for the default constructor, but also declares properties and initializes them from the parameters.

(Note that I've listed B before A. This is intentional.)